# Obtaining a formal functional description of this particular binomial sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, binomial-distribution

I am trying to simplify this expression below:

$\Gamma(x,n)=(1+x)^n-(1+x)^{1-n}~\forall~\mathcal{S}:=\{x,n\in\mathbb{R}\lvert x\in(-1,~1),n\geq1\}$

like $\Gamma(x,n)=\eta(.)x$.

So far I am using binomial expansion to simplify this, but the problem is that I am not able to formally define a functional description of $\eta(.)$.  I have also given the point where I am stuck:

$\Gamma(x,n)=\left[(2n-1)+\left[\frac{(n-2)+(n+1)}{3!}+\frac{(n-2)(n-3)-(n+1)(n+2)}{4!}x+\frac{(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)+(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{5!}x^2\cdots\right]x^2\right]\cdot x$

where,

$\eta(.)=\left[(2n-1)+\left[\frac{(n-2)+(n+1)}{3!}+\frac{(n-2)(n-3)-(n+1)(n+2)}{4!}x+\frac{(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)+(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{5!}x^2\cdots\right]x^2\right]$

Could anyone help me to achieve a functional description for the infinite sequence of $\eta(.)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x \ne 0$ we have:

$\frac{\Gamma(x,n)}{x}=\frac{(1+x)^{2n-1}-1}{x}* \frac{1}{(1+x)^n}=\frac{(1+x)^{2n-1}-1}{1+x-1}* \frac{1}{(1+x)^n}=[(1+(1+x)+(1+x)^2+...+(1+x)^{2n-2}]* \frac{1}{(1+x)^n}$.

Does this help ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because my function $x$ includes zero :(.

Comment: Observe that $\Gamma(x,n)= x[(1+(1+x)+(1+x)^2+...+(1+x)^{2n-2}]* \frac{1}{(1+x)^n}$ for all $x$

Comment: Could you give an elaborate answer, please. I mean in your answer section :).

Comment: Since $\Gamma(x,n)=(1+x)^n-(1+x)^{1-n}$, I would expect something like this $((1+x)^{2n-1}-1)* \frac{1}{(1+x)^{n-1}}=\Gamma(x,n)$, which should be converted to a form of $\Gamma(x,n)=\eta(.)x$. So, I am not getting how you got to your final solution there, So could you explain that.

Comment: Apparently working really well, with some tweaking, +1 for the cheeky (motivated) solution!! and could you please tell what class of series is this? It will be really useful if you can say that as well.

Comment: Got it!! I suppose it is geometric series :)